# Ошибка подключения пакета gulp-imagemin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Установил gulp-imagemin командой `npm i -D gulp-imagemin` после подключил его в gulpfile.js `const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");`

При попытке запустить gulp получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Tema05\Desktop\web\2021\pattern\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\Tema05\Desktop\web\2021\pattern\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js from C:\Users\Tema05\Desktop\web\2021\pattern\gulpfile.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Tema05\Desktop\web\2021\pattern\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\package.json.
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tema05\Desktop\web\2021\pattern\gulpfile.js:35:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Из текста ошибки решил что нужно подключить через import `import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";` после чего ошибка изменилась

```
import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at requireOrImport (C:\Users\Tema05\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11)
    at execute (C:\Users\Tema05\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:37:3)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\Tema05\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:211:24)
```

Погуглив нашёл другой вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module и попытался использовать решение в виде добавления в файл package.json `"type": "module"` но это ломало подключение остальных пакетов. Все подключали gulp-imagemin через require, а также в первой ошибке сказано что нужно наоборот удалить `"type": "module"`. Решил что иду не в том направлении и проблема в установке.

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN pattern@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\sass\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ gulp-imagemin@8.0.0
updated 1 package and audited 836 packages in 8.795s

27 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 6 vulnerabilities (1 low, 2 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Сначала установил uuid версии 7.0.3 при помощи команды `npm i uuid`. Далее посмотрел детали 3 уязвимостей статута "high" которые появились после установки gulp-imagemin.

```
High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         trim-newlines                                                 

  Patched in      >=3.0.1 <4.0.0 || >=4.0.1                                     

  Dependency of   gulp-imagemin [dev]                                           

  Path            gulp-imagemin > imagemin-gifsicle > gifsicle > logalot >      
                  squeak > lpad-align > meow > trim-newlines                    

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1753                             


  Package         trim-newlines                                                 

  Patched in      >=3.0.1 <4.0.0 || >=4.0.1                                     

  Dependency of   gulp-imagemin [dev]                                           

  Path            gulp-imagemin > imagemin-mozjpeg > mozjpeg > logalot >        
                  squeak > lpad-align > meow > trim-newlines                    

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1753                             


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         trim-newlines                                                 
  Patched in      >=3.0.1 <4.0.0 || >=4.0.1                                     

  Dependency of   gulp-imagemin [dev]                                           

  Path            gulp-imagemin > imagemin-optipng > optipng-bin > logalot >    
                  squeak > lpad-align > meow > trim-newlines                    

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1753
```

Перешёл по ссылке https://npmjs.com/advisories/1753 где было сказано что нужно установить trim-newlines нужной версии. Я установил trim-newlines версии 4.0.2 командой `npm install trim-newlines`

После переустановки gulp-imagemin нечего не изменилось. Просьба обновить uuid и 3 уязвимости остались. Чистка кеша с атрибутом --force, переустановка и полное удаление node.js по инструкции в вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows нечего не изменили.

Поиск решения приводил к ошибкам установки или ошибкам непосредственной работы пакета. Никаких похожих проблем именно с подключением не нашёл.

Содержимое gulpfile.js

```
const src_folder = "src";
const dist_folder = "dist";
const path = {
    src: {
        html: [src_folder + "/*.html", "!" + src_folder + "/_*.html"],
        scss: [src_folder + "/scss/*.scss", "!" + src_folder + "/scss/_*.scss"],
        js: [src_folder + "/js/*.js", "!" + src_folder + "/js/_*.js"],
        img: src_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
        fonts: src_folder + "fonts/*.ttf"
    },
    dist: {
        html: dist_folder,
        css: dist_folder + "/css",
        js: dist_folder + "/js",
        img: dist_folder + "/img",
        fonts: dist_folder + "/fonts"
    },
    watch: {
        html: src_folder + "/*.html",
        scss: src_folder + "/scss/*.scss",
        js: src_folder + "/js/*.js"
    },
    clean: dist_folder
}

const del = require("del");
const { src, dest, watch, series } = require("gulp");
const fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include");
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
const groupcssmediaqueries = require("gulp-group-css-media-queries");
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const cleancss = require("gulp-clean-css");
const uglifyes = require("gulp-uglify-es").default;
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
// const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin"); <------------------------------------------------------------
const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();

function cleanFiles() {
    return del(dist_folder);
};

function parseHtml(done) {
    src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.html));
    done();
};

function parseScss(done) {
    src(path.src.scss)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(groupcssmediaqueries())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ["last 5 versions"]
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.css))
        .pipe(cleancss())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.css));
    done();
};

function parseJs(done) {
    src(path.src.js)
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.js))
        .pipe(uglifyes())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.js));
    done();
};

function parseImg(done) {
    src(path.src.img)
        //.pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.img));
    done();
};

function browserInit(done) {
    browsersync.init({
        server: dist_folder,
        notify: false
    });
    done();
};

function browserReload(done) {
    browsersync.reload();
    done();
}

function watchFiles(done) {
    watch(path.watch.html, series(parseHtml, browserReload));
    watch(path.watch.scss, series(parseScss, browserReload));
    watch(path.watch.js, series(parseJs, browserReload));
    done();
};

exports.default = series(cleanFiles, parseHtml, parseScss, parseJs, parseImg, browserInit, watchFiles);
```

Содержимое package.json

```
{
  "name": "pattern",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "gulp",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "fls",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.5",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify-es": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.38.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "trim-newlines": "^4.0.2",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: А можете пожалуйста сбросить ваш файл gulpfile.js?

Comment: Да, я добавил содержимое в вопрос.

Comment: `function parseImg(done) {
    src(path.src.js)
        //.pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.js));
    done();
};`
Почему в папку js
Вы закоментировали pipe так и нужно?
`gulp.task('default', gulp.series(...))` есть еще паралель почему не используете?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Comment: pyduti это ещё не готовый код, а просто скопированная функция. Сначала я хочу разобраться с подключение пакета. Как раз в этом и заключается проблема.

Comment: @nörbörnën, если Вы хотите сказать что я должен использовать import, то изменение подключения на `import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";` вызывает другую ошибку которая есть в моём вопросе (2 сверху).

Я впервые установил node.js ради gulp 2 дня назад и не понимаю как всё устроено. Можете пожалуйста подсказать в каком направлении мне двигаться используя Вашу ссылку?

Comment: ну прочитайте пожалуйста https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=ru&u=https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Comment: @nörbörnën, Я правильно понимаю мне нужно переместить мой проект CommonJS в ESM?

Comment: Артем лучше потренеруйтесь на том что вам скинул в ответе так как если хотите разобраться лучше это делать на том что работает

Comment: @pyduti, мой код полностью рабочий есть закомментировать подключение gulp-imagemin

Comment: Хорошо хорошо, я вам верю что он работает так предложил по структуре по мне легче читать то что снизу,

`() => (
 gulp.src('src/images/*')
  .pipe(imagemin())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
);` это в документации

`function parseImg(done) {
    src(path.src.img)
        //.pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(dest(path.dist.img));
    done();
};` это у вас

Comment: Перед src нет слова gulp так и нужно?

Comment: @pyduti, не вижу разницы в простоте чтения. Варианты практически идентичны. По поводу scr, посмотрите как я подключаю gulp. Это сделано для того чтобы не писать перед каждой функцией "gulp.".

Comment: Артем к сожалению мне сложновато разобраться видимо что-то изменилось с того момента когда я собирал проекты через gulp я почитаю документацию на сайте у них и если никто не даст ответ вечерком вам отпишу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gulpfile.js

```js
    const  gulp = require("gulp"),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');
    sass.compiler = require('node-sass');
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    pipeline = require('readable-stream').pipeline,
    minifyjs = require('gulp-js-minify'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

/***                        PATHS                        ***/
const paths = {
    src: {
        scss: './src/scss/*.scss',
        js: './src/js/*.js',
        img: './src/img/*'
    },
    dist: {
        css: './dist/css',
        js: './dist/js',
        img: './dist/img',
        self: './dist/'
    }
}
/***                        PATHS                        ***/

/***    FUNCTIONS    ***/
const buildSCSS = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.src.scss)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.css))
                .pipe(browserSync.stream())
)

const buildJS = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.src.js)
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.js))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
)

const buildImg = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.src.img)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.img))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
)


const cleanBuild = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.dist.self, { allowEmpty: true })
    .pipe(clean())
);

const watcher = () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch(paths.src.scss, buildSCSS).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(paths.src.js, buildJS).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(paths.src.img, buildImg).on("change", browserSync.reload);
};

const imgMin = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.src.img)
        .pipe(imagemin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.img))
);


const compresedJS = function () {
          return pipeline(
              gulp.src(paths.dist.js),
                uglify(),
                    gulp.dest(paths.dist.js));
};

const minifyJS = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.dist.js)
      .pipe(minifyjs())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.js))
  );

const minifyCSS = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.dist.css)
      .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.css))
);

const autopref = () => (
    gulp.src(paths.dist.css)
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: false
        }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.css))
);

/***    TASK    ***/

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
    cleanBuild,
    imgMin,
    buildSCSS,
    buildJS,
    buildImg,
    autopref,
    minifyCSS,
    buildJS,
    compresedJS,
    minifyJS,
    watcher
));
```

package.json

```js
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.html",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url": ""
    },
    "homepage": "",
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
        "gulp-js-minify": "0.0.3",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "readable-stream": "^3.6.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Заметил что используете gulp-imagemin версии 7.1.0. Посмотрел историю версий пакета https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin и понял что использую новую версию 8.0.0 вышедшую совсем недавно, а все примеры его использования видел на старой версии 2 летней давности.

После установки старой версии всё работает как и задумано, но меня всё равно настораживает наличие 3 уязвимостей в пакете trim-newlines после установки.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло когда скатился ниже 8.0.0. Всем советую..

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

откатил imagemin до 7.1.0 . Заработало.

в терминале `npm install gulp-imagemin@7.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае помог даунгрейд gulp-imagemin до ^7.1.0

Ответ выше в целом о том же самом, просто неявно. Что и мотивировало меня написать ответ. К тому же рейтинг не позволяет отставить комментарий

Моя конфигурация - node 16.13.0, yarn 1.22.5, gulp ^4.0.2