# gulp, imagemin: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: javascript, gulp

Только начинаю работать c gulp, делаю все по примеру видеоурока. После попытки подключить плагин imagemin выдает следующую ошибку:

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\User\Desktop\fls-gulp\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\User\Desktop\fls-gulp\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js from C:\Users\User\Desktop\fls-gulp\gulpfile.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\User\Desktop\fls-gulp\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\package.json.

Вот мой файл gulpfile.js:

```js
let project_folder="dist";
let source_folder="#src";

let path={
  build:{
    html: project_folder + "/",
    css: project_folder + "/css/",
    js: project_folder + "/js/",
    img: project_folder + "/img/",
    fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
  },
  src:{
    html: [source_folder + "/*.html", "!" + source_folder + "/_*.html"],
    css: source_folder + "/scss/style.scss",
    js: source_folder + "/js/script.js",
    img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
    fonts: source_folder + "/fonts/*.ttf",
  },
  watch:{
    html: source_folder + "/**/*.html",
    css: source_folder + "/scss/**/*.scss",
    js: source_folder + "/js/**/*.js",
    img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
  },
  clean: "./" + project_folder + "/"
}

let {src, dest} = require('gulp'),
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  browsersync = require("browser-sync").create(),
  fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include"),
  del = require("del"),
  scss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
  autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
  group_media = require("gulp-group-css-media-queries"),
  clean_css = require("gulp-clean-css"),
  rename = require("gulp-rename"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify-es").default,
  imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");

  function browserSync(params){
    browsersync.init({
      server:{
        baseDir: "./" + project_folder + "/"
      },
      port:3000,
      notify:false
    })
  }

  function html(){
    return src(path.src.html)
      .pipe(fileinclude())
      .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())
  }

  function css(){
    return src(path.src.css)
      .pipe(
        scss({
          outputStyle: "expanded"
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        group_media()
      )
      .pipe(
        autoprefixer({
          overrideBrowserslist: ["last 5 versions"],
          cascade: true
        })
      )
      .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
      .pipe(clean_css())
      .pipe(rename({
        extname: ".min.css"
      }))
      .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())    
  }

  function js(){
    return src(path.src.js)
      .pipe(fileinclude())
      .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
      .pipe(
        uglify()
      )
      .pipe(rename({
        extname: ".min.js"
      }))
      .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())
  }

  function images(){
    return src(path.src.img)
    .pipe(
      imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false}],
        interlaced: true,
        optimizationLevel: 3    // 0 to 7

      })
    )
      .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())
  }

  function watchFiles(params){
    gulp.watch([path.watch.html],html);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.css],css);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.js],js);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.img],images);
  }
  function clean(params){
    return del(path.clean);
  }

  let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images));
  let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);

  exports.images = images;
  exports.js=js;
  exports.css=css;
  exports.html = html;
  exports.build = build;
  exports.watch = watch;
  exports.default = watch;
```

Да,и мой файл package.json вообще не содержит строчки "type": "module". Извините,я совсем ничего в этом не понимаю, просто хотела сделать по примеру урока...

Вот файл package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "fls-gulp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Сборка gulp",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "fls",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.5",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify-es": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.42.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "node": "^16.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Приложите `package.json`.

Comment: Приложила. Я ведь правильно понимаю, что имеется в виду файл,который лежит в той же папке, что и gulpfile.js? Потому что package.json есть также в node_modules/gulp-imagemin

Comment: `package.json` есть в каждом пакете - он зависимости описывает.

Comment: То есть я правильный файл приложила?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1319194/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-gulp-imagemin) уже задавался. Проблема в том, что [gulp-imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin) перешёл на [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), посему решения два:

1. Откатить до версии `^7.1.0`
2. Прописать в `package.json` `"type": "module"` и переделать весь `gulpfile.js` на `import`.

Comment: Откат до версии 7.1.0 помог, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
let image;
import("gulp-imagemin").then(res => {
  image = res;
});
```

Можно так прописать, как динамический импорт, чтобы не переписывать весь файл (как советуют выше)

Answer (score 0):

В файле **package.json** добавить **"type": "module"**

```
"name": "example",
"version": "1.0.0",
//добавил
"type": "module",
```

Изменить в файле **gulpfile.js**

```
//было 
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
exports.img = img;
exports.default = img; 
//стало
import gulp from 'gulp'; //использовать gulp.src, gulp.dest
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin';
export { img };
export default img;
```